# Hot to add a loading class until the form data are returned using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On submit, I would like to add a .loading class in the #results until the data are returned, so the class is removed.

How does the code change ?

```
$(function(){
    $("#myform").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();


        $.post('mail.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
            $('#results').hide().html(data).fadeIn('slow').delay(2000).hide(1);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```
$(function(){
    $("#myform").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        // Add the class here:
        $("#results")
            .show()
            .addClass("loading");

        $.post('mail.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
            $('#results')
                .hide()
                .html(data)
                .fadeIn('slow')
                .delay(2000)
                .hide(1)
                .removeClass("loading"); // Remove the class here.
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Right you are, I've edited the above snippet to now work. Also, here's a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/fkw5s/6/

Comment: Now I cant get any return. The loading class is appeared now for ever. Previously, even if the loading class worked for the first time, it returned the data. In mail.php there is a simple light `mail()` function.

Comment: Is there an error from the ajax? In the fiddle I changed the `"mail.php"` to an `""` so that it would post to itself (because mail.php doesn't exist in that context).

Comment: No, there is not an error because I checked it with other methods. Everything seems to work.

Comment: Worked. I restarted Firefox and worked. Sometimes I don't understand how computers "think". Thank you. Accepted and +1